# Arduino, if else LED "stuck"

Tags: arduino

So the code is not working properply, there are two leds that wont turn off "highliten" the problem. when i run the Else part of the program. i want to turn them off in the else part. :)

## include

```
byte ledPin[] = {8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13}; //--------------------------------.
int ledDelay;                           // Del 1
int direction = 1;
int currentLED = 0;
unsigned long changeTime;
int potPin = 0; 


Servo myservo;  // create servo object to control a servo 

int potpin = 0;  // analog pin used to connect the potentiometer
int val;    // variable to read the value from the analog pin 
int va;

void setup() 
{ 

  pinMode(4, OUTPUT);
  pinMode(5, OUTPUT);
  pinMode(6, INPUT);
  myservo.attach(3); // attaches the servo on pin 9 to the servo object 
  Serial.begin(9600);

  for (int x=0; x<6; x++) {
  pinMode(ledPin[x], OUTPUT); }
  changeTime = millis();
} 

void loop() {
   int  on = digitalRead(6);
if (on == HIGH)
{
  myservo.attach(3);
// Here is the problem!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!
      if va < 523)
{
  digitalWrite(5, HIGH);
}
else if (va > 555)
{
   digitalWrite(4, HIGH);
}

else
{
   digitalWrite(4, LOW);
   digitalWrite(5, LOW);
}
// Here is the problem!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!
  digitalWrite(8, LOW);
  digitalWrite(9, LOW);
  digitalWrite(10, LOW);
  digitalWrite(11, LOW);
  digitalWrite(12, LOW);
  digitalWrite(13, LOW);
  va = analogRead(potPin);            // reads the value of the potentiometer (value between 0 and 1023) 
  val = map(va, 0, 1023, 0, 179);     // scale it to use it with the servo (value between 0 and 180) 
  myservo.write(val);                  // sets the servo position according to the scaled value 
  delay(1);                           // waits for the servo to get there 

}
else
{
  myservo.detach();
  digitalWrite(5, LOW);
  digitalWrite(4, LOW);
  ledDelay = analogRead(potPin) / 4;
  if ((millis() - changeTime) > ledDelay) 
  {
  changeLED();
  changeTime = millis();
  }
}
}

  void changeLED() {
   for (int x=0; x<6; x++)
   {
   digitalWrite(ledPin[x], LOW);
   }
   digitalWrite(ledPin[currentLED], HIGH);
   currentLED += direction;
  if (currentLED == 6) {direction = -1;}
  if (currentLED == 0) {direction = 1;}
  }
```

in advance Thank you!

Comment: I won't claim to understand all of the above, but it seems to me that in `if (currentLED == 6) {direction = -1;}` towards the very end the value should be 5, not 6.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Right at the end of the sketch you have the following line:

```
if (currentLED == 6) { direction = -1; }
```

I think, without actually running the program, that the problem is here.  In the previous line you have added one to the value of `currentLED` and you are checking to see if you have gone off the end of the `ledPin` array.  You change the direction but you don't reset the currentLED position to be back inside the `ledPin` range.

The next time `changeLED` is called it tries to call `digitalWrite(ledPin[currentLED], HIGH);` but the value of `currentLED` is 6, which is outside the `ledPin` array. The Arduino probably gets upset at this point.

I think you simply need to change the statement to check whether `currentLED == 5` rather than `6`.  This will mean that next time that `changeLED` is called the last LED will be turned on and the value of `currentLED` will be decremented (`direction == -1`), keeping it inside the `ledPin` range.